# WLST find(): Find is not supported for this tree

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I have some problem with `WLST` find
when I am trying to find some `Mbean` or `Attr`
even if they are located in the current `pwd()` I got the same error:

```
wls:/base_domain/domainRuntime/ServerRuntimes/AdminServer> find('State')
```

Find is not supported for this tree

And I can not find anything against MBean tree.

How to solve this find problem? please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` command is not accessible from within `domainRuntime()` but you can use it with `serverRuntime` and `serverConfig`. Instead if you want to see server states, simply do a `connect()` and then make calls to get each individual server MBean and then get the State.

```
def checkHealth(serverName):
  while 1:
    slBean = getServerBean(serverName)
    status = slBean.getState()
    print 'Status of Managed Server is '+ status 

def getServerBean(svrName):
  domainRuntime()
  slrBean = cmo.lookupServerLifecycleRuntime(svrName)
  return slcBean
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13813/reference.htm#i1064028